# Hibernate with legacy DB schema and composite FKs and PKs

Tags: java, hibernate

I am having some trouble trying to find a solution for this and I think it may not be possible at all, but I'll still give it a try here.
So lets pretend my legacy DB schema on MySQL with MyISAM (no FKs) has the following 2 tables:

```
TblOrder
ORDERID (INT)    PK
CUSTOMERID (INT) PK
REPID (INT)      PK
ISORDER (INT)    PK
other columns...

TblOrderPos
ORDERID (INT)    PK
POSITIONID (INT) PK
other columns
```

What would my annotations have to look like to allow TblOrder to have a Set of TblOrderPos (identyfied by ORDERID) and TblOrderPos a private TblOrder instance? I did create EmbeddedId objects for both tables and everytime I try to create a property with @ManyToOne or @OneToMany overriding @JoinColumns Hibernate complains that the number of PK columns does not match (well it cant).

I really hope somebody has an idea or if it's possible at all.

-----------update------------

On TblOrder

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="shoporder")
@JoinColumn(name="ORDERID")
public List<Orderposition> getOrderpositions(){
    return this.positions;
}

public void setOrderPositions(List<Orderposition> positions){
    this.positions = positions;
}
```

On TblOrderPos

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="ORDERID")
public Shoporder getShoporder(){
    return this.shoporder;
}

public void setShoporder(Shoporder order){
    this.shoporder = order;
}
```

That's the error I keep getting:
A Foreign key refering TblOrder from TblOrderPos has the wrong number of column. should be 4

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommended, but it's doable with composite-id:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html

Comment: Perhaps he was asking specifically about how to do that using annotations.

Comment: Yes, that would be helpful. If it's not possible with annotations, an XML example would help too.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with annotations, because I've used such structures.

Have you properly used `@ManyToOne` annotation to link with table with composite PK? It should look like that:

```
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "WOJ_ID", referencedColumnName = "WOJ_ID"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "POW_NR", referencedColumnName = "POW_NR"),
        })
```

I'm using `@IdClass` annotation and provide classes for composite PK, some example is posted in my answer to other question:
[Why is my EmbeddedId in hibernate not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923611/why-is-my-embeddedid-in-hibernate-not-working/9923865#9923865)